# Boto3: How to get Instance ID created from Spot Request?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Sending out a spot request and waiting for the spot request to be fulfilled seems to work.

Next, how can I get the ec2 instance id/object that is created in order to check e.g. IP address etc.?

That's the code I have so far:

```
def create_spot_instance():
    print("Send Spot Request")
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    res = ec2_client.request_spot_instances(
        ...
    )
    request_id = res['SpotInstanceRequests'][0]['SpotInstanceRequestId']
    print("Wait for request to be fulfilled...")
    waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter('spot_instance_request_fulfilled')
    waiter.wait(SpotInstanceRequestIds=[request_id])
    print("Wait for ec2 instance to boot up...")
    # TODO: get instance id the spot instance created
    # TODO: wait until spot instance is booted up
    # TODO: return object of ec2 instance
```

Comment: did you try describe_spot_instance_requests? for the instance ids created by spot?

Refer: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_spot_instance_requests

Comment: Yep, oversaw all the describe functions. That way I also got a hold of the ec2 instance and was able to solve all the remaining "TODOs" in the code above.
If you put it down as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: done from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

describe_spot_instance_requests should give the for the instance ids created by spot.

Refer:https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_spot_instance_requests